# OpenCL performance: using arrays of primitives vs arrays of structures

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to use several arrays of doubles in a kernel that are all the same length. Instead of passing each double* in as a separate argument, I know I can define a structure in the .cl file that holds several doubles and then just pass into the kernel one pointer for an array of the structures instead.

Will the performance be different for the two ways? Please correct me if I am wrong, but I think passing individual double pointers means the access can be coalesced. Will accessing the structures also be coalesced?

Comment: Hi Thomas, what I meant was that instead of having 20 arrays of 100 doubles each, I would have an array of 100 structures each containing 20 doubles - not a single structure with 20 double pointers.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I thought you meant bundling `double*` arrays into a single structure, not splitting the array across multiple structures.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The structures and the single elements will have the exact same performance.
Supose you have a big array of doubles, and the first work item uses 0, 100, 200, 300, ...  and the next one uses 1, 101, 201, 301, ...

If you have a structure of 100 doubles, in memory the first structure will be first(0-99), then the second(100-199) and so on. The kernels will acess exactly the same memory and in the same places, the only difference is how you define the memory abstraction.

In a more generic case of having a structure of different element types (char, int, double, bool, ...) it may happen that the aligment is not as if it were a single array of data. But it will still be "semi-coalesced". I would even bet the performance is still the same.

Comment: I don't quite follow... If there are many arrays, each 100 long as you propose, then the first work-item accesses a single double in the first 100 doubles and nothing else in the first 100 doubles. In comparison lets say you have a structure to contain the 20 doubles (lets say there were originally 20 arrays of 100 length each), then the first work-item only accesses the first 20 doubles and nothing else. So, that's very different, would that affect coalescing?

Comment: Yes, they are different. But it will affect it the same way as if you do the same usage of the memory ordered in a single long array. So, the structure is not the issue here. Only how you use that memory.

Comment: DarkZeros, you are totally right. I just sucked it up and tried it. I used 8 million structs of 4 doubles compared to 4 arrays of doubles each 8 million long. The operation was to sum the the 4 i-th doubles for each of the 8 million threads. On my 7970 GHZedition the struct implementation takes ~6% more time. I did a dozen runs or so and the results are very consistent. Anyways, that's a small penalty for the huge improvement in programming ease!

Answer (score 0):

As long as your structures don't contain any pointers what you say is absolutely possible. The primary impact is generally, as you've already considered, the effect this has on the coalescing of memory operations. How big an effect is down to your memory access pattern, the size of your struct and the device you're running on. More details would be needed to describe this more fully.

Saying that, one instance where I've used a struct in this way very successfully is where the element being read is the same for all work items in a work group. In this case there is no penalty on my hardware (nvidia GTX 570). Also it is worth remembering that in some cases the added latency introduced by the memory operation being serialised can be hidden. In the CUDA world this would be achieved by having a high occupancy for a problem with a high arithmetic intensity.

Finally it is worth pointing out that the semantic clarity of using a struct can have a benefit in and of itself. You'll have to consider this against any performance cost for your particular problem. My advice is to try it and see; it is very difficult to predict the impact of these issues ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it is the same performance. However if you access some of the members more often, using several segregatedvarrays will have much more performance, due to cpu cache locality. However most operations will be more difficult when you have several arrays.